# Wrong path chosen in VsCode (Python)

Tags: visual-studio-code, directory

Whenever I launch a python code in vscode, it does not use the file's path but the folder I opened for the interpreter.
It gets annoyning because I know it would work in other applications like Sypder and I do not know why can't I find a parameter that let me say "open Python interpreter with the file's directory for its path".
could you help me ?

Let's say I open this folder with the files inside in vscode :

- Main_Folder

  - Secondary_Folder
    Code.py
    - csv_folder
    info.csv

If I want to read the 'info.csv' file, I would like to use this code
`import csv file = open('csv_folder/info.csv,'r')`
However, I have to use this code because it starts at the origin of the folder :
`import csv file = open('Secondaary_Folder/csv_folder/info.csv,'r')`